# Calculate new position values in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, geometry, calculus

I have a document which containing some elements. The document is an INDD document. I am trying to show it in a webview but in a smaller size than the original size.
I am using ImageMapper (ASP.NET) to mark the different elements in the webview. 
The problem is that I don´t get the correct positions in of the different spots in the webview.
I got the correct size of the new spots but not the position.
I made the calculations in the following way:

```
Original size (INDD document)
DocumentWidth = 768
DocumentHeight = 1024
New Size (Size of the webview)
Width = 522
Height = 696

percentW = newWidth(Webview)/DocumentWidth
percentH = newHeight(Webview)/DocumentHeight;
```

From these percent values I am calculating all the new values I will need in the ImageMapper (top,left,bottom,right).

Formula for that

```
myPrecent = (percentW/percentH) * 100;
        result =  myPrecent * ((top,left,right,bottom) / 100);
```

The result variable shall represent the new value which will be used in the spots within ImagMapper.

I suppose that I am thinking wrong in my calculation but I cant figured out what I´m doing wrong. So I will be appreciate if someone has any idea what I have doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

don't think of them as percentages, instead, think of them as scaling factors.

```
verticalScaling = Height/DocumentHeight
horizontalScaling = Width/DocumentWidth

newTop = Top * verticalScaling
newLeft = Left * horizontalScaling
newBottom = Bottom * verticalScaling
newRight = Right * horizontalScaling
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I actually got the same values from these calculation. I think the problem is with the X and Y position in the webview comparing to the INDD document. I am using an asp:Image control in the webview.